# OpenLDAP: Index to olcDatabase not respected

Tags: debian, ldap, openldap

I am creating databases like the following (called from an application):

```
$ ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// <<EOF
dn: olcDatabase={20}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {20}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/domain.tld
olcSuffix: dc=domain,dc=tld
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by * read
olcRootDN: cn=user,dc=domain,dc=tld
olcRootPW: {SSHA}XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcDbIndex: cn,uid eq
olcDbIndex: uidNumber,gidNumber eq
olcDbIndex: member,memberUid eq

EOF
```

OpenLDAP responds with

```
adding new entry "olcDatabase={20}mdb,cn=config"
```

But the index number in front of `mdb` is not respected. In reality the database ends up in `olcDatabase={2}mdb.ldif`.

This can also be seen when dumping the config:

```
$ slapcat -b cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/domain.tld
olcSuffix: dc=domain,dc=tld
...
```

The index is just incremented every time I add a new database. Which makes sense but I need to be able to set it explicitly so my program knows where its data is stored.

The strange thing is that I am pretty sure it worked in the beginning. I have tried reinstalling (with `--purge`) several times to no avail.

I am using Openldap 2.4.40 on Debian:

```
Linux LINUX_LDAP_DEV 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) i686 GNU/Linux
```

In `ldap.conf`I am only setting `TLS_CACERT`.

Comment: Why does your program need to read `con=config` at all? It should just connect to the base DN `dc=domain,dc=tld` and shouldn't care about the internals of OpenLDAPs configuration...

Comment: It's because my program creates (and removes) LDAP databases for another program.

Answer (score 1):

Query `cn=config` for the appropriate `olcSuffix` and use the resulting dn instead of relying on external knowledge of the numeric index.

Comment: That would be neat but I need the index to get the filename corresponding to the database in `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/` so I can delete it later. Of course it would be best if I could delete the database using LDAP itself but that seems to not be possible.